# Can you identify the CLI tool for page speed benchmarking that produced this histogram?

Tags: page-speed

I used a CLI program for benchmarking page load speed that produced a histograms like this in its output:

```
  0.969 [1]     |■■
  1.700 [17]    |■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
  2.430 [2]     |■■■■■
  3.161 [1]     |■■
  3.891 [0]     |
  4.622 [0]     |
  5.352 [0]     |
  6.083 [0]     |
  6.814 [0]     |
  7.544 [0]     |
  8.275 [1]     |■■
```

I need this tool very indispensably but also very intermittently, and I keep forgetting its name. Google results are completely dominated by highly promoted SaaS tools, even if I say "CLI" a 100 times in the query.

(The output above was copied from a slack conversation, but the name of the tool wasn't mentioned).

**Note well**: this is a "question about the", not a "question about a". Please don't suggest alternatives. This is EXPLICITLY not a recommendation request, it is a request to help identify a specific software tool. It should not attract "opinionated answers" because there is exactly one correct answer to the question.

Comment: How do you have output from the program without the name of the program itself?     It's too bad you can't google "■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■" and get meaningful results.

Comment: These black squares are not redactions, they are the bars of the histogram that the program of interest outputs. I have the output because it was preserved in a slack conversation into which it had been manually pasted, back when I still remembered how the program was named and could use it. But I didn't paste the program's name into that conversation!

Comment: I'll buy your argument that it isn't quite like a recommendation question and might be allowed here.  Maybe we should have a discussion in meta specifically about whether "identify this software" questions should be allowed or disallowed.  For now I'm re-opening.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little strange to need a very specific tool, because there are other ones doing the same thing (displaying an histogram).

I found that one https://golangrepo.com/repo/six-ddc-plow-go-testing-frameworks that seems to show kind of the same histogram as your example but not 100%. Difficult to see if it can be just a display difference or version difference. Your output is not really enough.

`plow` produces this:

```
Latency Histogram:
  141µs  273028  ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
  177µs  458955  ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
  209µs  204717  ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
  235µs   26146  ■■
  269µs    6029  ■
  320µs     721
  403µs      58
  524µs       3
```

Comment: What did you search for to find this?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller "benchmark cli http histogram" and I looked in the first page of results. Another search gave a link to https://github.com/denji/awesome-http-benchmark which lists a lot of tools, with at least two of them having "histogram" in their description. But the OP was adamant of not wanting any alternative...

Answer (score 0):

Self-answer for eternal reference: the program is `hey`. I first recalled (with a little help from a colleague) that one tool we used in the past was `ab` aka apache benchmark, but it doesn't provide a histogram, so I googled "alternatives to apache benchmark" and found `hey`, and this is the thing.

Comment: Yes, `ab` is kind of an ancestor to many, otherwise you can find on https://github.com/denji/awesome-http-benchmark many other ones.  `hey` is mentioned there but without an "histogram" keyword. Its main page at `https://github.com/rakyll/hey` does not show an output example nor says it does histogram. If you want to help this software you could try to improve both points so that it is easier to find it.